# Integration with constants help

Tags: integration

The original integration formula I had was:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dx'}{\sqrt(4\pi Dt)}\exp(\frac{-|x-x'|^2}{4Dt})A\exp(-\beta(x'-b)^2)$ where D=$\frac{ih}{2m}$

after a bit of algebra and completing the square it simplifies down to:

$\frac{A}{\sqrt(4\pi Dt}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx'\exp(-(\alpha+\beta)(x'-\frac{\alpha x+\beta b}{\alpha+\beta})^2 - (\alpha x+\beta b)^2)$ where $\alpha$ = $\frac{1}{4Dt}$

however now I don't know how to integrate that to get a final result. The many constants are confusing me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all the constant terms before the integral sign, ending up with 
$$\frac{A}{\sqrt(4\pi Dt}\exp(- (\alpha x+\beta b)^2)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-(\alpha+\beta)(x'-\frac{\alpha x+\beta b}{\alpha+\beta})^2 \right)\ dx'$$
The integrand can be compared with the Gaussian density function $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x'-\mu)^2)$ which will integrate to $1$ for $-\infty<x<\infty$.

For your integral you have $\sigma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(\alpha+\beta)}}$ and $\mu=\frac{\alpha x+\beta b}{\alpha+\beta}$. Thus the integral is
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp\left(-(\alpha+\beta)(x'-\frac{\alpha x+\beta b}{\alpha+\beta})^2 \right)\ dx'=\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha+\beta}}$$

Comment: I'm sorry I've never done gaussian integration before so I've not come across that formula... is that the only way to do this question?

Comment: The Gaussian integral is a widely used technique (I can't think of any other way), for when you have an $x^2$ term in the exponential, which is described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral